# Does a Microcontroller act as a Capacitive load or resistive?

Tags: microcontroller, buffer, load, capacitive, unity-gain

I'm designing a unity gain buffer (IC MCP6002) and in the datasheet, it says that a  small series resistor is required at the output, if the load is capacitive and is >100pF.
The input of the buffer is a varying ADC value from one microcontroller and the output of the buffer is given to the ADC input pin of a second microcontroller.

Is the microcontroller at the output considered a capacitive load in any way?

Comment: The datasheet for the "second microcontroller" will specify the input capacitance.

Comment: And if it doesn't, figure it'll be around 10pF.  It should be in or close to the "electrical characteristics" section.  I actually looked up a data sheet for an ATTINY, and at first read couldn't find a capacitance spec for the input pins.

Comment: I'm using the PIC24FJ64GB004 as the output microcontroller. On page 267 of its datasheet, Figure 22-2, mentions 'input capacitance' and the 'sample/hold capacitance'. So the total capacitance comes up to about 15.4pF. Have I missed out on any other capacitance?

Comment: only track to ground capacitance which is tiny. so yer ok

Comment: Thank You everyone for your help.